# How to compare a string column to a number (as a decimal) in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, compareto

I have a database with an amount field - it's a decimal, although the database schema has the column defined as a string. I want to be able to run a Linq query to find values based on a number for the amount.

There are questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578231/issues-doing-a-string-comparison-in-linq) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365122/how-to-compare-a-string-column-value-in-a-linq-query) that talk about using the CompareTo method, but that doesn't work in this situation.  For example, I have the following bill amounts in the database:

```
556
130
1450
410
```

the following code:

```
from t in test
where t.BillAmount.CompareTo("50") > 0
select t
```

will return value `556` but not any of the other values, even though they are all above the decimal value of 50.

Changing the where line to:

```
    where t.BillAmount.CompareTo("50") < 0
```

will return `130`, `1450`, and `1450` as those are "less" then 50 as a string, but not as a number.

I'm not using the entity framework, so I can't do something like:

```
where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t.BillAmount).Trim() > 50
```

I also don't have any control over the database schema, so I can't change these values. How can I compare the BillAmount field to a number and return the values above/below it?

Comment: Maybe Convert.ToDecimal() will help?
Select(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s))

Comment: You say you don't use the EF, so what is the type of test? Datatable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to use Entity Framework to cast a String to Decimal.

You can simply use the `Convert` call.

```
var x = from t in test 
        where Convert.ToDecimal(t.BillAmount) > 50 
        select t
```

or with Lambda expression:

```
var x = test.where(p=>Convert.ToDecimal(p.BillAmount) > 50);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to use `let`, which will let you have a temporary variable as part of the LINQ query. Something like this should work:

```
from t in test
let amount = Convert.ToDecimal(t.BillAmount)
where amount > 50
select t
```